# Why is OkObjectResult ignoring JsonIgnore?

Tags: c#, json, azure-functions

I'm returning an object from my Azure function using `OkObjectResult`, but the object's JSON still contains properties I've marked `JsonIgnore`. Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Details:

I have this class:

```cs
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
// ...
public class Example
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string C { get; set; }
}
```

When returning from an Azure function, if I do:

```cs
var result = new Example() { A = "Ayy", B = "Bee", C = "See" };
return new OkObjectResult(result);
```

...the JSON returned is (I've added formatting):

```json
{
    a: "Ayy",
    b: "Bee",
    c: "See"
}
```

Notice that the `JsonIgnore` attribute didn't take effect, the JSON has a `c` property.

But if I serialize explicitly:

```cs
var result = new Example() { A = "Ayy", B = "Bee", C = "See" };
return new OkObjectResult(
    JsonSerializer.Serialize(
        result,
        new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase}
    )
);
```

...`c` is left out as desired:

```json
{
    a: "Ayy",
    b: "Bee"
}
```

Why isn't the property being left out when I give the object to `OkObjectResult` directly, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the class code uses the wrong `JsonIgnore` attribute because of this:

> ```cs
> using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
> ```

As of this writing, Azure functions (still) use `Newtonsoft.Json` by default,<sup>1</sup> so the property is marked with the wrong attribute, and the serializer doesn't know to leave it out.

To fix it, import `Newtonsoft.Json` instead:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json; // <====================
// ...
public class Example
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string C { get; set; }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> If you use Visual Studio's Add... > Azure Function, the template it creates includes the import of `Newtonsoft.Json`, which is the only reason I realized this. See also [this related issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5469) (thanks for that, [Eldar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12354911/eldar)!).